# Perforce Changelist and shelve command

Tags: perforce

I am very new to Perforce and just started using it.
After syncing my code using $p4 sync command i started editing a few files.

- $p4 edit file1
- $p4 edit file2
- $p4 edit file3

These files were getting added to my default changelist. For collaborating with my team i wanted to create a changelist. For creating a changelist i ran $p4 change and removed "file1" from the changelist description. Now when i run $p4 opened. It gives an output similar to this.

- //depot/... /file1 edit default change (text)
- //depot/... /file2 edit default 111 (text+k)
- //depot/... /file3 edit default 111 (text+k)

Now i have the following questions in my mind:

- Which changelist am i currently working on is it default or 111 ??
- what is the meaning of (test + k)?
- When i make changes to file2 and file3 it is getting synced to changelist 111 and when i make changes to file1 it gets synced to default changelist . I am highly confused how is this happening ?
- Also one more thing i am confused about is if do $p4 shelve will my changes disappear and will be reapplied only when i run unshelve command for the changelist created ?? Is this similar to git stash and git stash apply ?

It will be great if someone can answer these questions in detail. Any tutorial suggestions for Perforce will also be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation for a Perforce tutorial is the Perforce User's Guide.  Here's the section on changelists:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/intro/chapter.working_in_perforce.html#working_in_perforce.working_with_files.changelists

> Which changelist am i currently working on is it default or 111 ??

Both!  Both of these are pending changelists in your workspace.

> what is the meaning of (text+k)?

The thing in parentheses is the "filetype".  `+k` is a "filetype modifier" meaning that keywords (special words like `$Id$` and `$Revision$` and `$Author$` in this file will be automatically expanded to appropriate values when you submit.

> When i make changes to file2 and file3 it is getting synced to changelist 111 and when i make changes to file1 it gets synced to default changelist . I am highly confused how is this happening ?

Nothing is getting "synced" anywhere yet -- the pending changelists are just containers that reference the different files.  When you `shelve` or `submit`, **then** the files associated with those changelists will get sent to the server and will be accessible by other clients.  Since `shelve` and `submit` are changelist-level operations, only the files in those changelists are affected -- that's the point of having different pending changelists.  You have all of the pending files in your workspace, but you can split up which ones get sent to the server at which times (it's a little like pushing different branches in git, but not -- you can do this on every operation in Perforce even when you aren't branching because each file is versioned individually rather than having the entire tree versioned as one atomic blob).

> Also one more thing i am confused about is if do $p4 shelve will my changes disappear and will be reapplied only when i run unshelve command for the changelist created ?? Is this similar to git stash and git stash apply ?

No, `p4 shelve` only syncs the shelved change on the server with the local files in your workspace -- it doesn't in itself change your workspace.  The equivalent of "stashing" would be to `p4 shelve` and then to `p4 revert` to wipe out the workspace changes.  `shelve` on its own is a little more like doing a `git push` to a branch -- you keep your local copy but now it's also on the server (but not part of the "master" history).  (It's not exactly the same though -- to be honest if you're brand new to Perforce I'd stick to regular old "submit" in a regular old branch since that's the basic workflow.  Sharing work via shelves requires a lot more manual work since each shelf is like its own little mini-branch with no versioning.)